# What's the difference between IEnumerable and Array, IList and List?

Tags: c#

What's the difference between `IEnumerable` and `Array`?

What's the difference between `IList` and `List`?

These seem to have the same function.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

`IEnumerable` provides only minimal "iterable" functionality. You can traverse the sequence, but that's about it.
This has disadvantages; for example, it is very inefficient to count elements using `IEnumerable`, or to get the nth element.
But it has advantages too; for example, an `IEnumerable` could be an endless sequence, like the sequence of primes.

`Array` is a fixed-size collection with random access (i.e. you can index into it).

`List` is a variable-size collection (i.e. you can add and remove elements) with random access.

`IList` is an interface which abstracts list functionality (count, add, remove, indexer access) away from the various concrete classes such as `List`, `BindingList`, `ObservableCollection`, etc.

Comment: According to the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826658/what-is-faster-or-preferred-ienumerable-toarray-or-tolist. Count on IEnumerable is almost the same beacuse it tries to call Count on ICollection

Comment: Yes and no.  The Count() extension method checks if the IEnumerable is also an ICollection, and calls its Count property if it is. If the IEnumerable *isn't* an ICollection then Count() falls back to iterating the sequence.  Maybe I should have said "it is very inefficient to count elements using *only* IEnumerable," because of course the presence of IEnumerable doesn't stop you using a more efficient method if the object has one, and the LINQ to Objects extension methods do exactly that.

Answer (score 21):

IEnumerable is an interface that allows the iteration through a collection of items (e.g. via the foreach keyword).

An array is a .NET intrinsic.  It holds items of the same type, but it is of a fixed size.  Once you create an array with x elements, it cannot grow or shrink.

IList defines the interface for a list, and also implements IEnumerable.

List implements the IList interface; it is a concrete type of list.

The difference between .NET Lists and arrays is that lists can have elements added to them -- they grow to be big enough to hold all of the required items.  The list stores this internally in an array and, when the array is no longer big enough to hold all of the elements, a new array is created and the items copied across.

IList & arrays both implement IEnumerable.  That's how interfaces work -- classes implement the contract and behave in a similar fashion and can be treated similarly as a result (you know that the class implements IEnumerable, you don't need to know the hows or the whys).  I suggest you read up on interfaces and so forth.

Comment: Adding this comment for readers who don't read all the answers: arrays and List<> both implement IList<> (arrays implement much of it explicitly, presumably because many of the members throw a NotSupportedException). It's also more correct to say that IList inherits from IEnumerable than to say it implements it.

Answer (score 10):

Generation of an IEnumerable collection is lazy.
Example:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetTwoInts()
{
  yield return 1;
  yield return 2;
}
public void Something()
{
  var twoInts = GetTwoInts();
}
```

In the method Something the call to GetTwoInts() will not actually result in the method GetTwoInts being executed since the enumeration is never iterated over.

Comment: Could you please elaborate it a little? I am not sure if I understood it right. Can you show a line of code later on which will actually result in that method being executed? 

Thanks!

Comment: @paaone put `twoInts` in a `foreach` or call `twoInts.ToList()`.

Answer (score 9):

IEnumerable and IList are [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx).  Array and List are classes.  Array implements IEnumerable.  List implements IList which extends IEnumerable.

Edit: as itowlson mentionned in a comment,  Array also implements IList.

Comment: Nor did I!  What happens if you start calling IList.RemoveAt on an array, though?

Comment: It throws a NotSupportedException.  (Note IList.RemoveAt and similar IList methods are explicitly implemented on Array so that they don't show up on a normal Array reference!)

Comment: @itowlson I would point that only System.Array (a class per se) does implement IList, but T[] doesn't implement IList<T>. T[] implements IEnumerable<T> instead. I think the OP didn't necessarily ask for System.Array when asking for "Array" IMHO

Answer (score 2):

`IEnumerable` is a general-purpose interface that is used by many classes, such as `Array`, `List` and `String` in order to let someone iterate over a collection. Basically, it's what drives the `foreach` statement.

`IList` is typically how you expose variables of type `List` to end users. This interface permits random access to the underlying collection.

Answer (score 2):

To complement the other answers, note that there is a **performance difference** between `IList<T>` and `List<T>` when executing a foreach statement.

That's because the iterator object returned by `List<T>.GetEnumerator` is a value-type whereas the one returned by `IList<T>.GetEnumerator` is a reference-type, and thus requires a memory allocation (see [Enumerator of value type of list in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036148/enumerator-of-value-type-of-list-in-c-sharp)).

In my opinion, `IList<T>` is not a very good interface anyway. For instance calling `Add` can throw (see [Why array implements IList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968708/why-array-implements-ilist)). If you need encapsulation you'd be better off using `IEnumerable<T>` or `IReadOnlyList<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers, understanding the different between Enumerable vs List/Array when using LINQ can have huge performance impact. In short, Enumerable can be perceived as a query builder while List/Array is the result of the query.

In the context of LINQ to SQL using EntityFramework, the former is just building the SQL query without executing it against the database nor loading any data into memory while the later is the opposite. That's why we would defer calling `.ToList()` until we need it in the memory to perform business logic.

In other context, LINQ expression returning IEnumerable will defer execution until `.ToList()` is called. Consider example below:

```
void Main()
{
    var w1 = "AB".AsEnumerable();
    Console.WriteLine($"W1: 1");
    w1 = w1.Where(W1);
    Console.WriteLine($"W1: 2");
    w1 = w1.Where(W2);
    Console.WriteLine($"W1: 3");
    w1.ToList();    
    Console.WriteLine($"----------");

    var w2 = "CD".AsEnumerable();
    Console.WriteLine($"W2: 1");
    w2 = w2.Where(W1);
    Console.WriteLine($"W2: 2");
    w2 = w2.ToList();
    Console.WriteLine($"W2: 3");
    w2 = w2.Where(W2);
    Console.WriteLine($"W2: 4");
    w2.ToList();    
    Console.WriteLine($"----------");
}

bool W1(char arg)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"W1:{arg}");
    return true;
}

bool W2(char arg)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"W2:{arg}");
    return true;
}

OUTPUT:
W1: 1
W1: 2
W1: 3
W1:A
W2:A
W1:B
W2:B
----------
W2: 1
W2: 2
W1:C
W1:D
W2: 3
W2: 4
W2:C
W2:D
----------
```

In first example, two `.Where()` is being "appended" and executed together at the end when `.ToList()` is called with item "**A**" going through the pipe first then item "**B**", hence seeing "**AABB**" in the output, while in the second example, the `.Where()` is executed every time if we call `.ToList()` immediately afterwards, hence seeing "**CD**" and then "**CD**" again, output twice. Therefore, every time an Enumerable is converted to a List or an Array will cost one **O(n)** iteration over all items in the collection which will have performance impact when the collection is large.

Although we don't trend to write code this way calling `.ToList()` in between LINQ calls but it would happen more frequent when we factor code into reusable methods that return `List/Array` rather than `IEnumerable`.

This however doesn't mean we should always operate on `IEnumerable`. As mentioned by [towlson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61700/itowlson), that operations such as `.Count()` will cause iteration over the collection while a List or Array would have this info pre-calculated and therefore converting to `List/Array` would be more efficient if you plan to call `.Count()` multiple times. This is also why there is a `.Count` property on a List rather than a `.Count()` method to count it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but still thought of replying.
IEnumerable is a behavior while Array is a data structure(Contiguous collection of elements with fixed size, facilitating accessing elements by indexes) .
When an Array implements IEnumerable, it is supposed to depict IEnumerable inherent property  also (of facilitating iteration over the collection).

Answer (score 0):

If someone is reading this recently, `IEnumerable` could be lazy, so you'll have to be careful if your iterator has business logic within it:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetTwoInts()
{
    Console.WriteLine("1");
    yield return 1;
    Console.WriteLine("2");
    yield return 2;
}

public void Something()
{
    var twoInts = GetTwoInts();
}
```

Using the example in the answers, both `Console.WriteLine`s will not be called until `twoInts` are "used", i.e. used in a foreach-loop, or `ToArray` is called, which might be unintuitive.