# Why I get a System.NullReferenceException on this code?

Tags: c#, list, null

I have this code :

```
IList<MyObject> myObjects = new List<MyObject>();
if (param != null)
{
    myObjects = (from ... LINQ1 ...).ToList();
}
else
{
    myObjects = (from ... LINQ2 ...).ToList();
}

foreach (MyObject myObject in myObjects)
{
}
```

when the foreach start, I get a System.NullReferenceException. Why? And how can I fix it? Looks strange...

Comment: You haven't given enough code for us to know. Perhaps one of your queries contains a null reference which you're using in a comparison etc? A short but complete program which demonstrates the problem would help. Also, there's no point in giving `myObjects` an initial value if you're then just going to overwrite it.

Comment: Please post the entire code. The problem is probably in the code snippets that you have deleted.

Comment: Also, why do you initialize `myObjects`?

Comment: Give us the stack trace of the exception, so we can investigate the problem

Comment: may be you have to use List<MyObject> instead of IList<MyObject>... Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367539/ilistint-vs-listint

Comment: Impossible fto help. The error is somewhere ni: "(from ... LINQ2 ...)" .- the evaluation of that must throw a null pointer exception internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is being overwritten by one of the LINQ queries which is most likely returning a null value.

Also is myObjects meant to be an `IList<MyObject>` or `List<MyObject>` ?

Comment: How? "...).ToList();" is supposed to return a list, even if empty.

Comment: @TomTom, yes but it is possible to write a linq query that returns a null ref exception, because of something in the query, the To List is just enumerating through the items and executing the expression

Comment: Yes, that is possible- that the not shown part throws a null reference WHEN EVALUATING.

Comment: @TomTom, are you saying that .ToList() on a null value is supposed to return an empty list?

Comment: No, i said that ToList always returns a list, even when no element is in teh query. So, the result will never be a null. BUT: as Ben said, it is possible something in the query throws the exception when evaluating.