# How to create an extension method to handle bindinglist.removeall with predicate input

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, extension-methods, predicate

```
myGenericList.RemoveAll(x => (x.StudentName == "bad student"));
```

Works great, but a bindinglist does not have this method. How can I create an extension method for the bindinglist that takes as input a predicate and does the magic like the canned removeall for List

thankyou

Comment: The extension method is going to do the same thing as if you did it manually.

Comment: Damn. i was hoping for some cool lambda trick or something. Anyone ?

Comment: It's not really a lambda trick per se, lambdas only will help you with the predicates.  As for Linq, you can use Linq to help with selecting, but the Linq methods don't really mutate IEnumerable<T> sequences.  So you'd need a combo of select, then remove.

Comment: thanks svick and James. Learned many new things from your responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like I said in a comment, there is no magic in extension methods, just write the code the same way as if you wrote it normally, just put it in a static method in a static class and use the `this` keyword:

```
public static void RemoveAll<T>(this BindingList<T> list, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach (var item in list.Where(predicate).ToArray())
        list.Remove(item);
}
```

You have to use `ToArray()` (or `ToList()`), because `Where()` is lazy and only enumerates the collection when needed and you can't enumerate changing collection.

Although this solution is quite slow (O(N<sup>2</sup>)), because every `Remove()` has to look through the collection to find the correct item to remove. We can do better:

```
public static void FastRemoveAll<T>(this BindingList<T> list, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (predicate(list[i]))
            list.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

This uses the fact that we can get to i-th item in constant time, so the whole method is O(N). The iteration is easier to write backwards, so that indexes of items we have yet to consider aren't changing.

**EDIT:** Actually the second solution is still O(N<sup>2</sup>), because every `RemoveAt()` has to move all the items after the one that was removed.

Comment: True, either way they perform in the same order of magnitude.  The linq expression in each of our two solutions is probably more maintainable for a novice developer who doesn't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

```
public static class BindingListExtensions
{
    public static void RemoveAll<T>(this BindingList<T> list, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        // first check predicates -- uses System.Linq
        // could collapse into the foreach, but still must use 
        // ToList() or ToArray() to avoid deferred execution                       
        var toRemove = list.Where(predicate).ToList();

        // then loop and remove after
        foreach (var item in toRemove)
        {
            list.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

And for those interested in the minutia, seems ToList() and ToArray() are so close to the same performance (and in fact each can be faster based on the circumstance) as to be negligible: [I need to iterate and count. What is fastest or preferred: ToArray() or ToList()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826658/what-is-faster-or-preferred-ienumerable-toarray-or-tolist)

Comment: That first `foreach` could be easily avoided using `ToArray()`.

Comment: True, I thought of that right as I entered it and then updated it.  Used ToList() instead, though.

Comment: yeah, but I think `ToArray()` is slightly clearer here, because you don't mutate the result and array is less mutable than list.

Comment: In general I agree, but confined within the method it's fairly safe either way since we're only using it as a temporary list, if I were returning the results I'd be much more concerned, of course.

Comment: thanks for your response. Upvoted since your solution is the easiest to understand.