# What's the difference between List<string> and IEnumerable<String>?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between IEnumerable and Array, IList and List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764748/whats-the-difference-between-ienumerable-and-array-ilist-and-list)

What's the difference between the above two?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764748/whats-the-difference-between-ienumerable-and-array-ilist-and-list

Answer (score 77, accepted):

A `List<string>` is a concrete implementation of `IEnumerable<string>`. The difference is that `IEnumerable<string>` is merely a sequence of `string` but a `List<string>` is indexable by an `int` index, can be added to and removed from and have items inserted at a particular index.

Basically, the interface `IEnumerable<string>` lets you stream the `string` in the sequence but `List<string>` lets you do this as well as modify and access the items in the lists in specific ways. An `IEnumerable<string>` is general sequence of `string` that can be iterated but doesn't allow random access. A `List<string>` is a specific random-access variable-size collection.

Comment: This answer was more helpful than those at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764748/whats-the-difference-between-ienumerable-and-array-ilist-and-list

Comment: What does a concrete implementation mean? Does it mean a list inherits from ienumerable?

Comment: @user1534664: No. It means it inherits from `IEnumerable` *and* it's not abstract, it's actually constructible.

Answer (score 12):

different.

IEnumerable enables you to iterate through the collection using a for-each loop.

And IEnumerable just have method GetEnumerator.

And List it implement many interface like IEnumerable, Ilist, etc. So many function in List.

In performance IEnumerable faster than List.

Answer (score 4):

`IEnumerable<T>` is an interface.  It must be implemented.

`List<T>` is one implementation of `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 2):

One is an interface:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx

The other is a class that implements that interface:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Also, List is an array that grows when you add elements to it, while IEnumerable allows implementers to be used in a foreach.

Answer (score 2):

The first is a concrete `List` of strings, the other is any class implementing `IEnumerable<string>`