# How I can Optimize this linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is there some way to optimize this query ?

```
_alternatives.Cast<AlternativePartName>()
                                .Where(alt => original.ToLower() == alt.CompName)
                                .Select(alt => alt.AltCompName).ToList();
```

I am profiling my application and this code is one of the bottlenecks 196 ms but it executed a lot of times.

Comment: don't optimize the query, but cache the result? That said, did you plug the provider to a log text writer, in order to see which queries are actually executed?

Comment: Is this linq query run against a database?

Comment: @ Lorentz Vedeler No it's against ArrayList

Comment: Is it possible to not use `.ToList()`? Instead enumerate over the items in the subsequent code.

Comment: Is this some kind of Key/Value stores? Are you using database or is this just objects?

Comment: also, why do you have to cast the items and do you implement a custom cast operator?

Comment: How many items do you have in the `_alternatives` array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of calling `ToLower` for each item, call it *only* once:

```
var lower = original.ToLower();

_alternatives.Cast<AlternativePartName>()
              .Where(alt =>  lower == alt.CompName)
              .Select(alt => alt.AltCompName).ToList();
```

Comment: Also can use `IEnumerable` instead of `ToList()`

Comment: IEnumerable is an interface. If you change the type to be IEnumerable there'll still be a List object which will be created and assigned to the IEnumerable. IEnumerable in itself can't hold any object.

Comment: @Selman22: Even if I call ToLower() on the collection it'll still work on each object in the collection, isn't it?

Comment: @sloth: I got your point. What you're saying is that there may be conditions where we may not iterate the result and in these cases ToList won't be required. Agreed, I thought that would be a trivial case but point taken.

Comment: @SidharthPanwar yes, it will compare each item with the lowerest version of `original`, instead of converting original to lower-case every time.

Comment: @Selman22: I'd rather go for String.Equals unless I need my collection values to be in lower case.

Comment: @SidharthPanwar Almost. If you iterate the result once, there may be no point in creating a `List<...>` and thus copying the data around. But if you iterate the result more than once, it will probably be better to store the result in a `List<...>` than executing the query multiple times.

Comment: @sloth: You're almost right. I got the crux of what you're saying. Here's a good link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180767/whats-the-difference-between-liststring-and-ienumerablestring. Check the reply marked as answer.

Comment: @SidharthPanwar *You're almost right. I got the crux of what you're saying.* I don't think so. I reckon you disregard the deferred execution of Linq queries.

Comment: @sloth: Got both your points - Deferred execution and the time we save with using IEnumerable over List.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to use more of your cores with `.AsParallel()` - this could be a improvement at huge lists with long strings

```
string lower = original.ToLower();
_alternatives.Cast<AlternativePartName>()
              .AsParallel()
              .Where(alt =>  lower == alt.CompName)
              .Select(alt => alt.AltCompName)
```

Comment: This is a great option, IMO. But be sure that your data set is big enough to take advantage of the parallelization. For smaller sets it'll slow down the query even more. Here's a good link - http://www.dotnetperls.com/asparallel

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that "original" and "CompName" are strings. If yes, then you should do the following:

```
_alternatives.Cast<AlternativePartName>()
                                .Where(alt => String.Equals(original, alt.CompName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                .Select(alt => alt.AltCompName).ToList();
```

Comment: why you think it will be faster ?

Comment: You'll be saving the cost of running ToLower() on each object in your collection. The bigger your collection is the more time you'll be spending on running ToLower(). Also, the standard way of comparing strings is using String.Equals and not the == operator.

Answer (score 0):

Using correct data structures is best way to increse performance. In your case, it would be better if you used dictionary with `CompName` being the key and list of `AltCompNames` being the item. The lookup would be blazing fast, because there would be no iteration, just single lookup. And keeping such simple structure up-to-date with adding and removing items should not be a huge problem.

Answer (score 0):

To call `orignal.ToLower()` only once won't change anything real in performance.

Try to use e.g. Parallel LINQ to get the result faster if you got enough CPU-Power left.

Answer (score -2):

I am not so good with the dot syntax, but this

```
.Select(alt => alt.AltCompName)
```

combined with this

```
_alternatives.Cast<AlternativePartName>()
```

Could be achived with the select directly making the AlternativPartName

```
select new AlternativePartName(){...}
```