# What is the difference between the non-generic IEnumerable and the generic IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, generics, syntax, ienumerable

Sorry for such a vague question, but I have been searching around for the best part of a day, I have read article after article (and many questions here) but just cannot find an easy to understand answer.

I (think I) know what IEnumerable is for, but I just can't understand what it means when it is defined with a generic type argument, for example:

```
IEnumerable<int> test = method();
```

This is just driving me mad! Please put me out of misery and explain what it means?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An `IEnumerable` is basically a collection of objects.  It has the method `GetEnumerator()` which allows you to iterate through all of the objects in the enumerable.

An `IEnumerable<int>` is basically a collection of integers.  It has the method `GetEnumerator()` which allows you to iterate through all of the integers in the enumerable.

`IEnumerable<int> test = method();` means that `method()` is getting a collection if integers from somewhere.  It could be a List, an array or some other data type, but it is definitely a group of them and they are all integers, and you have the ability to iterate through them.

This post may be helpful as well: [What's the difference between IEnumerable and Array, IList and List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764748/whats-the-difference-between-ienumerable-and-array-ilist-and-list)

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now, I didn't realise it could be a collection and I just didn't understand how it worked. Is there a good resource you can show that shows the benefits/pitfalls comparing IEnumerable/list/arrays as I really want to learn more. +1 (when I can!)

Comment: Lists and arrays both implement `IEnumerable`.  All the generic collections in `System.Collections.Generic` implement `IEnumerable<T>`.  You may be interested in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764748/whats-the-difference-between-ienumerable-and-array-ilist-and-list

Comment: Thanks... and marking as answer... You may want to edit/put that link in your main answer as well because that really has made me completely understand now.

Answer (score 2):

I just think of `IEnumerable<int>` the same way as I'd think of a `List<int>`, which comes a little bit more naturally I suppose. With the caveat that an `IEnumerable<int>` doesn't do quite as much as a `List<int>`, and that essentially it's just a *thing* of ints that can be enumerated

Comment: I don't really like this analogy.  A list assumes that the all the items are in one place.  Where as an `IEnumerable` just says that you can get all of the items in some sequence.  It's like the difference between a phone book and the internet.  I can get all the numbers for plumbers in Chicago from either place, but in the Phone Book, they are already in a list - whereas in an `IEnumerable` or on the internet, they can be whatever, I just need to know how to find them - I didn't downvote you though, I just think your answer could use a little more clarity.

Comment: user689466 is looking for a way to understand IEnumerable. Clearly there are differences - it's just a starting point with an easily understandable concept and once he groks that he can move on to understanding the subtleties between the two

Answer (score 2):

The word you're looking for is "generics", and the example you give is IEnumerable being used as a generic for items of type int.  What that means is that the IEnumerable collection you are using is strongly-typed to only hold int objects as opposed to any other type.

Google "C# generics IEnumerable" and you will find all of the information you want on this.

Answer (score 2):

An `IEnumerable` has a `GetEnumerator` method which will return an `IEnumerator`, whose `Current` method will return an `Object`.  An `IEnumerable<T>` has a `GetEnumerator` method which will return an `IEnumerator<T>`, whose `Current` method will return a `T`.  If you know in advance the expected type of the object to be returned by the enumerator, it's generally better to use the generic form.

Another distinction is that `IEnumerator<T>` inherits `IDisposable`, which allows code which is done with an enumerator to call `Dispose` on it without having to worry about whether it is supported.  By comparison, when using a non-generic `IEnumerator`, it's necessary to test whether it is `IDisposable` and call `Dispose` on it if so.  Note that use of the non-generic form of `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerator` does not relieve one of the requirement to call `Dispose`.  As an example, casting the vb-style Collection to `IEnumerable` and then calling `GetEnumerator` 100,000 times without calling `Dispose` will be extremely slow (many seconds, even on an i7) unless a garbage-collection happens to occur.  Disposing the `IEnumerator` after each call will speed things up more than a hundredfold.

Answer (score -1):

IEnumerable means it can be used in a foreach loop.

`items` can be used in the form of

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```