# c#: how do I remove an Item inside IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I was making a custom grid that accepts an IEnumerable as an Itemsource. However I was not able to remove an Item inside the itemsource during delete method. Will you guys be able to help me using the code below?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<MyData> source = new List<MyData>();
    int itemsCount = 20;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++)
    {
       source.Add(new MyData() { Data = "mydata" + i });
    }

    IEnumerable mItemsource = source;
    //Remove Sample of an mItemSource
    //goes here ..
}

public class MyData { public string Data { get; set; } }
```

Comment: You probably don't even need `mItemsource` since you are wanting to use the original list functionality of `source`. Just remove that and work with your local `source` variable.

Comment: I think you should also read this - what is the difference between ienumberable, array, IList and List http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764748/whats-the-difference-between-ienumerable-and-array-ilist-and-list?lq=1

Comment: Your code is not clearly showing what you are trying to do. You should show how you have some object that accepts your `IEnumerable`, so that it is clear that you *only have* an `IEnumerable`, and that the `List<T>` is just for example data reference.

Answer (score 7):

You can't.  [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) (and its generic counterpart [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx)) is for just that - enumerating over the contents of some collection. It provides no facilities for modifying the collection.

If you are looking for an interface that provides all the typical means of modifying a collection (eg. Add, Remove) then have a look at [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13) or [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6) if you need to access elements by index.

Or, if your goal is to provide an `IEnumerable` to something, but with some items removed, consider [`Enumerable.Except()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) to filter them out (*as it is enumerated*).

Comment: ...which means you can probably do `.ToList().Remove(whateverItem)` on your IEnumerable.

Comment: @Andrew That is a horribly inefficient way to accomplish this. Not to mention that it's not actually modifying the original `source` list, but rather a copy.

Comment: That's a good point. I don't guess you would ever need to do that, really.

Comment: Remember, any "decent" programmer can string [BCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_Class_Library) calls together to make things "work". A "good" programmer understands what the library is doing under the hood, and takes advantage of the proper data structures, algorithms, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Use while loop to traverse the list whilst delete.

```
int i = 0;
while(i < source.Count){
    if(canBeRemoved(source[i])){
        source.RemoveAt(i);
    }else{
        i++;    
    }
}
```

Comment: He wants to remove from `mItemsource` which is `IEnumerable`. Not `source`.

Answer (score -2):

I was able to remove Item from the Itemsource using dynamic

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<MyData> source = new List<MyData>();
        int itemsCount = 20;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++)
        {
            source.Add(new MyData() { Data = "mydata" + i });
        }

        IEnumerable mItemsource = source;

        //Remove Sample of an mItemSource

        dynamic d = mItemsource;
        d.RemoveAt(0);

        //check data
        string s = source[0].Data;
    }
    public class MyData { public string Data { get; set; } }
```

Comment: -1 This only works because **you know** that the `IEnumerable` is pointing to a `List<T>`. What happens if someone passes an array instead? It will blow up.