# Finding an object in a list, remove and return it

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [c#: how do I remove an Item inside IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856853/c-how-do-i-remove-an-item-inside-ienumerable)

I have an Inumerable of Objects `foo`.

```
 public IEnumerable<foo> listOfFoo{ get; set; }
```

Foo has Id and name lets say.

I want to pass an ID to a method and the method should remove the object with that ID from the  IEnumerable and return it.

Whats the best way of doing it?

Comment: [lol couldn't help myself...](http://www.memecreator.org/meme/one-does-not-simply-remove-items-from-ienumerable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible for any collection that implements `IEnumerable<foo>`. If it is for example a `List<foo>`, then it's possible to remove items for it, but if it is for example a `foo[]` it's not possible to remove items.

If you use a `List<foo>` instead:

```
public foo Extract(int id) {
  int index = listOfFoo.FindIndex(x => x.Id == id);
  foo result = listOfFoo[index];
  listOfFoo.removeAt(index);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I eded up using your approach. I dont think there is a issue working with the array index, right?

Answer (score 6):

`IEnumerable`s are read-only. You can't remove an object from one.

That said, you could do something like

```
public Foo QuoteRemoveUnquoteById(int id)
{
    var rtnFoo = listOfFoo.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == id);
    if (rtnFoo != default(Foo))
    {
        listOfFoo = listOfFoo.Where(f => f.Id != id);
    }
    return rtnFoo;
}
```

which just masks out the matching `Foo`? However, this will get less and less performant the more items you "remove". Also, anything else that holds a reference to `listOfFoo` won't see any change.

Answer (score 3):

You can't simply remove an item from an `IEnumerable`.

---

But you can either do the change in the underlying collection (e.g. if it is a `List` or something), or filter the `IEnumerable` using a `Where` clause.

If you need to remove items, you should use a collection that supports removing items, like `List<>`.

---

For example, you could have your backing field be of type `List<foo>`:

```
private List<foo> _listOfFoo;

public IEnumerable<foo> listOfFoo 
{ 
    get { return _listOfFoo.AsReadOnly(); } 
    set { _listOfFoo = value.ToList(); } 
}
```

And then remove items from `_listOfFoo`.

```
_listOfFoo.Remove(_listOfFoo.Single(foo => foo.ID == id_to_remove));
```

Answer (score 2):

IEnumarable is an interface for iterating thru a collection and there is no way to remove items without casting to some kind of collection.

read more here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx