# Why does List.Count() and IEnumerable.Count() return different results?

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable

We have this array in LINQ.

```
string[] colors = { "green", "brown", "blue", "red" };
```

and this code return 0.

```
var list = new List<string>(colors);
IEnumerable<string> q3 = list.Where(c => c.Length == 3);
list.Remove("red");
listBox1.Items.Add("Oh! That is : " + q3.Count());
```

and other return 1.

```
var list = new List<string>(colors);
List<string> q3 = list.Where(c => c.Length == 3).ToList();
list.Remove("red");
listBox1.Items.Add("Oh! That is : " + q3.Count());
```

Why it happen? What is the diffrence between list and Ienumerable?

Comment: [Deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx) is the term you're searching. Many [LINQ methods in `Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.100).aspx) are executed lazily.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between IEnumerable and Array, IList and List?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764748/whats-the-difference-between-ienumerable-and-array-ilist-and-list)

Comment: @bit: It's really not a duplicate of that. This is about deferred execution in LINQ, really.

Comment: @JonSkeet yep, my bad.. guess I misread it.

Answer (score 19):

The `Where` method doesn't *execute* your query - it just *builds* a query, which is then executed when the data is requested. This is known as deferred execution. So in your first snippet, the filter is only applied when `Count()` is called - which is *after* the `red` item has been removed.

In the second snippet, your call to `ToList()` forces the query to be executed immediately to build a new list. This is then completely independent of the original list - so removing an item from the original list doesn't affect the results.

This is *not* dependent on the declaration type of `q3` - the important difference is *just* the call to `ToList()`. So if you change the second snippet to:

```
var list = new List<string>(colors);
IEnumerable<string> q3 = list.Where(c => c.Length == 3).ToList();
list.Remove("red");
listBox1.Items.Add("Oh! That is : " + q3.Count());
```

... you'll see the same effect. The query will be executed before the item is removed, at which point the original list is irrelevant to the contents of `q3`.

For more details on the ins and outs of LINQ, you might want to read my [Edulinq blog series](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/).

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable` is an interface and a list is a class. 
And `IEnumerable` can only store the values but you cannot edit it like add or remove values.

Also when you do `.ToList()` the query is being performed on the database if you select items from the db.