# Which type should I return?

Tags: c#, linq

Here i Have two tables with some columns.Here my aim is i want to do GroupBy operatio using ChilsMaster

```
public partial class Master
{
    public int MasterId { get; set; }
    public string Prod_Name { get; set; }
    public string Produ_Adress { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Price { get; set; }
}

public partial class ChildMasterMaster
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MasterId { get; set; }
    public string SalesRec { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Prod_Deliver { get; set; }
}

public class Market_Masters
{    
    public int MasterId { get; set; }
    public string Prod_Name { get; set; }
    public string Produ_Adress { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Price { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public string SalesRec { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Prod_Deliver { get; set; }
}
```

Here I write one private file which contains both columns of the table by using this join:

```
 public IEnumerable<Market_Masters> GetMaster()
 {
     var x = from n in db.Masters
             join chil in db.ChildMasterMasters on n.MasterId equals chil.MasterId into t
             select new
             {
                 n.MasterId,
                 n.Prod_Name,
                 n.Produ_Adress,
                 n.Price,
                 Hello = t
             };
    return ???;
}
```

If I write `.ToList()` it throws an Exception

Comment: Give this a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764748/whats-the-difference-between-ienumerable-and-array-ilist-and-list

Comment: Error 1 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Project1.Models.Market_Masters>' F:\DotnetProject\Project1\Project1\Business\Master.cs 27 20 Project1

Comment: You're creating an anonymous type.  If you want to pass that data around I suggest creating a DTO class to contain it.  It seems you intended to do `select new Market_Maters { MasterId = n.MasterId, ...}` or similar.

Comment: You´re creating anonymous instances instead of instances of type `Market_Masters`. Create instances of the latter and return `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return anonymous types from a method (i.e. `select new { ... }`). You need to create a class for that or use `Market_Masters` if it is of that type, e.g.:

```
public IEnumerable<Market_Masters> GetMaster()
{
    var x = from n in db.Masters
            join chil in db.ChildMasterMasters on n.MasterId equals chil.MasterId into t
            select new Market_Masters()
                {
                    MasterId = n.MasterId,
                    Prod_Name = n.Prod_Name,
                    Produ_Adress = n.Produ_Adress,
                    Price = n.Price,
                    Hello = t
                };

    return x.ToList();
}
```

If the type returned is not `Market_Masters` you could do something like (replace `YourChildType` with your actual type):

```
public class MarketMastersWithHello : Market_Masters
{
    public IEnumerable<YourChildType> Hello { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public IEnumerable<MarketMastersWithHello> GetMaster()
{
    var x = from n in db.Masters
            join chil in db.ChildMasterMasters on n.MasterId equals chil.MasterId into t
            select new MarketMastersWithHello()
                {
                    MasterId = n.MasterId,
                    Prod_Name = n.Prod_Name,
                    Produ_Adress = n.Produ_Adress,
                    Price = n.Price,
                    Hello = t
                };

    return x.ToList();
}
```

Comment: i'm Getting Error as ers' does not contain a definition for 'Hello'

Answer (score 6):

You are currently returning an anonymous type defined by:

```
                select new
                {
                    n.MasterId,
                    n.Prod_Name,
                    n.Produ_Adress,
                    n.Price,
                    Hello = t
                };
```

You *cannot* expose that as a strongly typed return type, **precisely because** it is anonymous. There is no `Foo` for which you can say "this is `IEnumerable<Foo>`".

You should probably create a named `class` that matches what you want, and return `new YourNewType {...}` (and return `IEnumerable<YourNewType>`)